# Search for a value in Object Array using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an Object array. I need to apply **contains filter** for every property (it has to search for that keyword and return the object if any one of the properties contains entered value). Please let me know how to do `contains` search using Jquery/Javascript.

Example:

```
var itemPrices = [
    { 'custName': 'Mike', 'custid': '1'},
    { 'custName': 'secondMike', 'custid': '2' },
    { 'custName': 'Ben', 'custid': '3' },
    { 'custName': 'dan', 'custid': '4' }
];
```

So, from the above array, If I search for Mike it has to return the 2 records which contain mike in the custName or if I search for 1 it has to return the customer with id 1. So it has to search each and every property in each object and return the matched object.

It is like more of a general search in the object array.

Thanks

Comment: Looping through the object properties is better explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could filter the array by checking all properties.

If you have properties which are not strings, you need to convert to string before using [`String#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).

```js
function search(array, value) {
    value = value.toString().toLowerCase();
    return array.filter(function (o) {
        return Object.keys(o).some(function (k) {
            return o[k].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) !== -1;
        });
    });
}

var itemPrices = [{ custName: 'Mike', custid: '1'}, { custName: 'secondMike', custid: '2' }, { custName: 'Ben', custid: '3' }, { custName: 'dan', custid: '4' }];

console.log(search(itemPrices, 'Mike'));
console.log(search(itemPrices, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Damn your fast fingers :)

Comment: @OriDrori, it's the power of short variables names, or so. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @NinaScholz. What if I have the integer values in the Id field?

Comment: you could convert all values to string and test then, like the edit.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by iterating the array of objects, then the properties of each object like so:

```js
var matches = [];
var searchString = 'Mike';
var itemPrices = [
    { 'custName': 'Mike', 'custid': '1'},
    { 'custName': 'secondMike', 'custid': '2' },
    { 'custName': 'Ben', 'custid': '3' },
    { 'custName': 'dan', 'custid': '4' }
];

for (var i = 0; i < itemPrices.length; i++) {
    for(var prop in itemPrices[i]) {
        if (itemPrices[i][prop].includes(searchString)) {
            matches.push(itemPrices[i]);
            break;
        }
    }
}

console.log(matches);
```

As a function, because that is a more reusable solution:

```js
function searchObjectArrayProperties(searchString, arrayToSearch) {
  var matches = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayToSearch.length; i++) {
    for(var prop in arrayToSearch[i]) {
      if (arrayToSearch[i][prop].includes(searchString)) {
        matches.push(arrayToSearch[i]);
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  return matches;
}

var itemPrices = [
  { 'custName': 'Mike', 'custid': '1'},
  { 'custName': 'secondMike', 'custid': '2' },
  { 'custName': 'Ben', 'custid': '3' },
  { 'custName': 'dan', 'custid': '4' }
];

// Then use the function like:
console.log(searchObjectArrayProperties('Mike', itemPrices));
```

Comment: Looks good, but an object that has multiple matching properties will be returned as many times as it has matches. Better add a `break;`. And while you are at it, make it a code snippet!

Comment: Good call, fixed!

Answer (score 0):

```
const filterPrices = (arr, value) => arr
                                .filter(e => Object.values(e)
                                    .some(f => f.includes(value)));
```

This function should work. It takes the array of objects and a value to search for.
It filters the array, checking the values (`Object.values`) of the object, then checking if any value (`.some`) of the array of values includes the value searched for.

This assumes that you have support for `String.prototype.includes` and`Object.values` in the environment you are developing for.